# Как настроить порядок в слоях в канвасе, чтобы спрайты вне его перекрывали перекрывали только определенные элементы?

Tags: c#, unity3d, canvas, ui

Картина следующая: не могу понять как настроить слои.
Как сделать так, чтобы Asteroid проходил поверх Background-а канваса, но не ammo и life бара?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Порядок прорисовки ui сверху вниз. 2)  Какова ... вы делаете игру на канвасе?...

Comment: На канвасе у меня только фон, хп и патроны. Всё остальное вне его. И вот хотелось бы, чтобы это все остальное было поверх фона, но за хп и патронами

Comment: Z позиция не влияет, только порядок в иерархии, сверху вниз. Если нужны группы, как для хп баров, создавайте пустые обьекты, как каталоги (родители).

Comment: @Yaroslav есть ведь Order in Layer для настройки слоев

Answer (score 0):

На `Ammo Bar` и `Life Bar` нужно повесить еще по `Canvas`, выбрать там `override sorting` и поставить `order in layer`, допустим, 10.

У `Sprite Renderer` на Астероиде поставил `order in layer`, допустим, 5.

Тогда получится, что у бэкграунда леер 0, у баров 10, у астероида 5. Астероид выше бэкграунда, но ниже баров. При условии, что `Sorting layer` везде `default`.